# Custom Event Handling in Android

Tags: java, android, event-handling

I currently have a Blossom class (which are flower petals that fall from the top of the screen). I want to be able to register when they collide with something (say, the basket that catches them). For an easier example, maybe we could discuss how I would register when they fall out of the screen (y value is > 430). How would I do this? I've been reading up a lot on custom event handlers, but I haven't been able to find anything that dumbs it down for me...which is what I need. I am trying to figure out the "Mr. Happy Object" example ([Click Here](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2002-03/01-qa-0315-happyevent.html?page=1)) but I just can't work it out. Can anybody explain this with some rough examples, like, in very simplistic terms?